# multiple \subsection commands - one empty page and one overfull page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I a having trouble when compiling the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % espanol
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % graficos
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[textwidth=15.5cm,textheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont={footnotesize},textfont={footnotesize},width=.75\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Conceptos básicos}
    \subsection*{Elementos de un sistema de visión: esquema físico y breve explicación de sus partes}   
    \subsection*{Concepto de imagen digital}
    \subsection*{Definción de modelo de color. Explicación de todos los modos de color}
    \subsection*{Concepto de histograma y su utilidad}
    \subsection*{Etapas clásicas de un sistema automático de procesamiento de imágenes: esquema y breve explicación de cada elemento}
    \subsection*{Preprocesado: explicación de las operaciones}
    \subsection*{Operaciones morfológicas: concepto y explicación de dilatación y erosión}
    \subsection*{Concepto de filtrado y tipos}
    \subsection*{Concepto de convolución y aplicación de filtros paso bajo y paso alto. Ejemplo de un kernel de ambos tipos}
    \subsection*{Concepto y kernel Laplaciano}
    \subsection*{Concepto de descriptor, obtención y utilización}
    \subsection*{6 tipos de descriptores: ejemplo y explicación de en qué se basan}

\section{Aprendizaje}
    \subsection*{Aprendizaje supervisado vs. aprendizaje no supervisado}
    \subsection*{Etapas en desarrollo de un clasificador}
    \subsection*{Generalización, overfitting, underfitting}
    \subsection*{Algoritmo K-means}
    \subsection*{Evaluación de clasificadores: matriz de confusión, métricas de evaluación, métodos de estimación}
    \subsection*{Tipos de ensamble learning}
    \subsection*{Bagging}
    \subsection*{Boosting}


\section{Clasificación de imágenes}
    \subsection*{Qué es y en qué consiste la clasificación de imágenes}
    \subsection*{Explicación de las dificultades que pueden aparecer en la clasificación de imáenes}
    \subsection*{Modelo bag of visiual words: en qué consiste y etapas}
    \subsection*{Diferencia entre SIFT y dense SIFT}
    \subsection*{Qué es y cómo se obtiene un diccionario de palabras visuales}
    \subsection*{Representación de imágenes en el framework bag of words}
    \subsection*{Gradiente de una imagen: definición y partes en que se expresa}
    \subsection*{Cómo obtener el gradiente de una imagen}
    \subsection*{Etapas de cálculo de un descriptor HoG}
    \subsection*{Qué es clustering. Tipos de clustering}
    \subsection*{Algoritmo de Lloyd para el clustering k-means}
    \subsection*{¿K-means converge??A mínimo local o global?¿Diferencia?}
    \subsection*{Ventajas y desventajas de k-means}
    \subsection*{¿Qué es una frontera de decisión?}
    \subsection*{K-Nearest-Neighbours: en qué consiste}
    \subsection*{Modelo de clasificación logistic regression: en qué consiste}
    \subsection*{Qué es una función de coste}
    \subsection*{¿Por qué SVM es un clasificador de margen máximo?¿Cómo se maximiza este margen?}
    \subsection*{Kernels en SVM: definción y utilidad}

\section{Instance-object-retrieval}
    \subsection*{Condcepto de borde/edge y su detección}
    \subsection*{Detección de bordes con el Laplaciano de Gaussiana (LoG)}
    \subsection*{Detección de bordes con diferencias de Gaussiana}
    \subsection*{Las tres partes de un sistema de reconocimiento basado en características locales: detección, descripción y correspondencias}
    \subsection*{Concepto de esquina/corner y sus ventajas frente a bordes}
    \subsection*{Detector de esquinas de Moravec: etapas y explicación}
    \subsection*{Detector de esquinas de Harris: etapas y explicación}
    \subsection*{Concepto de blob}
    \subsection*{Detección de blobs invariante a la escala}
    \subsection*{SIFT: etapas y explicación}
    \subsection*{SIFT: detección de puntos característicos}

\end{document}
```

The result is a document that has an empty page I did not declare at the beginning and that ends by the second section that has been declared. The rest, is nowhere to be found:

[image]

---

What could this possibly be due to?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As a page break after a heading is not allowed, LaTeX is not happy if a document has only headings. You should put a bit normal text between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises because your document features 50 [!] `\subsection*` directives (as well as 4 `\section` directives) but *no material* actually belonging to any of the subsections. The `\section` and `\subsection` directives are set up by the LaTeX kernel to disallow page breaks between the headers and the first couple of lines of text that follow the respective headers. In your document, *there are no lines of text* -- just more `\subsection*` (and `\section`) directives. Because no page breaks are allowed, LaTeX ends up creating a massively overfull page.

A quick-and-dirty fix would be to perform a global search-and-replace operation in your editor, replacing all instances of `\subsection` with `\null \subsection` and then recompiling; that way, page breaks will be made possible. A real fix, naturally, would consist of actually providing non-trivial material below at least some -- and ideally all -- subsection-level headers.