# LaTex compiler refuses to start a new pdf page

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, compiling, page

I am writing a journal article using the following settings:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

    {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont

\title{This title}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

I examine

\end{abstract}


{\small\bfseries Keywords} Hello

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion}
\section{References}
\section{Conclusion}
\section{References}
\appendix
\section*{Appendix}

}
\end{document}
```

Everything was going well until my TexStudio stopped creating a new page automatically. Note that my Page number 2 is now above my Section Headings. If I enter more text, it disappears under page 2 and no page 3 is automatically created. Please help!

I tried to search on many forums if this error can be resolved. I also repasted my code on Overleaf.com compiler and I see the same problem - so there is no issue with my TexStudio compiler! There is a problem with my code as 'page breaking' is not happening automatically. 
[image: My Page]

Comment: Welcome! Whether or not a new page starts automatically depends on the document class and settings. By default, in an article class a section does not start a new page. Chances are that you compare this behavior to another class. If you need to change the behavior for a given class, `titlesec` is your friend.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thank you. It means as I fill up the sections - it would automatically create new pages.

Comment: Same problem as this: [multiple \subsection commands - one empty page and one overfull page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435201)

Comment: Thank you barbara beeton

Comment: Yes, basically. There document classes and sectioning commands that automatically issue a page break, e.g. `\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ABC}
\chapter{CDE}
\end{document}`. And you can change the behavior e.g. with `titlesec`.

Comment: Thank you @Schrödinger'scat for your help!

Comment: Is your problem solved now and the question answered by what barbara linked to? If so, we can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Overfull box and broken pagination](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57861)

Comment: @Johannes_B yes, it is solved. Thanks you for all your help!